# How to get all users except select user from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get the users from the `mongo database` using `mongoose`.
If i select a user i want to **eliminate** that user records and get all the remaining users from database.
how can i do that?

Comment: which parameter will decide about not selecting the user ?

Comment: whatever in record like name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try to use the query below:-

```
    UsersModel.find({ email: { $ne: 'testemail@email.com' } })
```

Let me know if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here User is the user model. we will get all users except the current user

```
 const users = User.find({ _id: { $ne: user._id } })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UsersModel.find({ email: { $ne: 'testemail@email.com' } })
```

for more follow this url

```
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to exclude just one user, you can use

```
db.collection.find( { name: { $ne: "name" } } )
```

And if you want to exclude more than one records. May be more than one selected records. This is the way to go

```
db.collection.find( { name: { $nin: ["name1", "name22"] } } )
```